# google map - Draw poly-line and move car on it

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am working on vehicle tracking system.
I have a lat long array like this:

```
{"lat":"18.4560183333","lng":"73.8247583333"},
{"lat":"18.4537883333","lng":"73.8249266667"},
{"lat":"18.4547783333","lng":"73.8247633333"},
{"lat":"18.4534366667","lng":"73.8220883333"},
...
```

Now I want to draw  poly-line and move the car over.
same like: https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3b3j61pq/4/

Please help me.

Comment: same as in this jsiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3b3j61pq/4/

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a marker with car image
2. Try this code and loop through the latlon array with a delay

   ```
   LatLng currentPos = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
   carMarker.setPosition(currentPos);
   double bearing = 0;
   if(previousLocation!=null)
      bearing = currentPos.bearingTo(previousLocation);   // returns values between -180 to 180

   float rotation = bearing;
   if(rotation<0)
      rotation= 360+rotation;         //haven't checked this hope this will correct the angle
   carMarker.setRotation(rotation);   //to rotate the carMarker along the polyline
   map.invalidate();

   previousLocation = currentLocation;
   ```

If still the carmarker is not moving try remove and adding it again in the loop